# How can I write quotation marks inside an Rmarkdown Latex equation?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

How can I write quotation marks inside an Rmarkdown Latex equation? I tried the below, but the quotation marks get turned into dashes/derivative notation

$$
'Quoted Text'
$$

I tried many other suggestions like

$$
``Quoted Text"
$$

But nothing seems to display the quote marks properly.

Comment: Though you're doing this in rmarkdown, this really is a LaTeX question, so should likely go where you can get a quick response: [tex.se]. (Some questions there that are related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289345, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135701, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333719.)

Comment: I tried the suggestions on that forum, but even though the equation is fine in Latex, once the Rmarkdown is rendered, the equation is not rendered properly

Comment: This suggestion works for straight double quotes,`\texttt{"Quoted Text"}` but also curious about single quotes and curly single and double quotes

Answer (score -3):

This works for me:

```latex
$$
H_{0}: \text{Hello, } `` \text{World”}
$$
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit more so your solution becomes more comprehensible.